# What are the guidelines for summer beach clothes in Morocco?

Tags: legal, safety, beaches, morocco, female-travellers

I would like to visit Morocco (the country on Africa, it is Arab).

I know the temperature there is good to go to beach. **Can I wear typical European beach clothes there? (I mean the beach clothes that any girl in Europe wear when she goes to the beach)**

Is it dangerous to do that there? because I know that their religion doesn't allow that, but I'm not sure if their government allow that. And even if they allow, will it be dangerous to do that?

Plus, is it necessary to put that thing to cover my hair while traveling there?

Comment: Frankly, I find the question unclear. "Beach clothes that any girl in Europe wear when she goes to the beach" can range from short pants and t-shirt to a bikini bottom, topless. There are quite different ideas about modesty throughout Europe, and even within the same culture, a walk around the beach and sunbathing are done in different clothing.

Comment: What kind of beaches in Morocco (the country, on Africa) were you planning to visit? If you only visit beaches that are on resorts in touristy towns on countries that are Arab, it's usually okay to wear whatever you'd wear anywhere else. But it's usually different in places locals go (I've not been to Morocco but this was true in Tunisia, the country on Africa, it is Arab)

Comment: @rumtscho you're nitpicking... First, topless sunbathing is only allowed in a few countries in Europe, so that clearly doesn't meet the criteria "that any girl in Europe wear". So, the question is about swimwear, t-shirts, shorts and sundresses. Clarifying which of these are okay when is hardly too much to cope with.

Comment: @rumtscho my friend if you didn't get what I meant by beach clothes, then I'm sorry I cant help you.

Comment: @user568458 Now I started planing the travel, i don't really know what city I'll visit, I'm now invistigating the country, i found agadir good but I'm not sure, it depends on the flight and the price to be honest.

Comment: @user568438 I think your first comment could be an answer if you expand it slightly.

Comment: @davidvc I considered it but I'll save that for someone who's travelled in Morocco. But it'll probably vary from beach to beach based on how touristy or conservative the town is, so I'd suggest taking a variety, including light tops that reach the elbows and light long shorts/skirts/dresses that pass the knees, then each beach, do what everyone else does. If it's anything like Tunisia and Egypt it'll range from beaches in tourist resorts where bikinis are fine, to beaches in conservative villages where locals swim wearing niqabs, and everything between.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest you follow the saying "when in Rome do as the Romans do". In other words, arrive to the beach fully clothed and look around to see what others are wearing. Then adapt. The customs are likely to vary depending on the region, the city and even the beach itself.

Generally speaking though, the consensus on the internet seems to be that bikinis are OK, especially in tourist regions and private resorts.  Topless sunbathing is not. Cover up the bikini when away from the beach/pool. Don't go to the restaurant/market/shop in a bikini.

All in all, if you feel uncomfortable and/or wish to avoid being looked at too much, dress slightly more conservatively than you would back home. This applies to both at the beach and in other everyday life situations. Finally, religious dress codes do not apply to non-religious/foreign women in Morocco. Indeed the country is fairly tolerant towards others, provided you don't attempt to break the boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Morocco a very safe place, I visited many times, and I love it. It's one of the more "European" country in North Africa. Then just respect another culture with some natural rules, you have to be careful to your clothes mainly when you are going to visit religious places.

You can travel without any hassle to about all the main point of interest. Marrakech, Rabat, Fez etc .

Then if you would like to go to the beach in topless for instance is not a good idea, even if you’re an atheist, respect that the people in the building are people of faith who take their beliefs seriously, when you are going to visit religious places and in Ramadan period

I do not recommend to hold value object (Rolex watch for example) if you intend to have a walk on the seaside in the night.

Please check this [link](http://www.viaggiaresicuri.it/paesi/dettaglio/marocco.html) , if you are a english speaking user you can try to translate with google translate :

Comment: can you explain the term "occidental" in this context please? it's not clear to me.

Comment: Occidental = European

Comment: Perdonami , ma sei italiana ?